# Why am I getting an error in this C program?

Tags: c

I am new to C programming but I stumbled on this code

```
int print(int nb)
{
    if (nb < 0) 
    {
        return (0);
    }
    printf("%d", nb + print(nb - 1));
    nb --;
    return (nb);
}

int main(void)
{
    print(4);
    return (0);
}
```

I ran the code and it gave me an output of `00246`
why is that the output that, looking at it logically, the answer is not suppose to start with a `0`

Comment: What happens when `nb == 0`? `if (nb < 0)` won't stop it from printing 0.

Comment: What output do you expect? Why do you think this is an error?

Comment: You need to ask yourself: what problem is recursion supposed to solve here? Because all it achieved was literally just to confuse the programmer. "I'm studying recursion" is not a valid reason for why a program would use recursion. The most important part of studying it is questioning what purpose it fills in real-world programs. And until you find out a reasonable answer to that question, refrain from using it. Sadly, beginner classes spend far too much time on understanding this exotic, mostly useless language feature.

Comment: To understand what recursion is, you must first understand recursion. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

print(4) -> print(3) -> print(2) -> print(1) -> print(0) -> print(-1)

print(-1) stops the recursion returning 0, thus a call to printf() is emitted with 0 + 0, which is 0.

print(0) ends with -1 as value, and a call to printf() with 1 + -1 is emitted, which is 0.

etc.